# Elasticsearch query gives "No handler for uri" using httplib in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, elasticsearch, urllib2, httplib

I am using the official [elasticsearch-py](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/index.html) library for connecting to a local instance of Elasticsearch (localhost, port 9200, ES version 1.6.0). This works well in standalone Python scripts, but I cannot get it to work with Google App Engine where I get the following error:

```
No handler found for uri [http://localhost:9200/transaction/websession/_search] and method [GET]
```

After some debugging, I have narrowed the problem down to App Engine's use of `httplib` for the urlfetch RPC proxy.

So basically, I can do this:

```
r = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:9200/transaction/websession/_search')
r.read()
```

but not this:

```
c = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost:9200')
c.request('GET', 'http://localhost:9200/transaction/websession/_search', None, {})
c.getresponse().read()
```

Is this a bug in Python? Or in Elasticsearch? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem is the current App Engine SDK. The request is created like this:

```
c.request('GET', 'http://localhost:9200/transaction/websession/_search', None, {})
```

when it should just be:

```
c.request('GET', '_search', None, {})
```

The weird thing is that the [latest source code version](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/urlfetch_stub.py) of the urlfetch stub seems to be very different from the [shipped SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads).